# Regex to match everything except a pattern

Tags: regex, emacs

Regex noob here struggling with this, which I know it will be easy for some of you regex gods out there!

Given the following:

```
title:      Some title
date:       2022-08-15
tags:       <value to extract>
identifier: 1234567
---------------------------

Some text
some more text
```

I would like a regex to match everything except the value of `tags` (ie the "<value to extract>" text).

For context, this is supposed to run on emacs (in case it matters).

EDIT: Just to clarify as per @phils question, all I care about extracting the tags value. However, this is via a package setting that asks for a regex string and I don't have much control over how it gets use. It seems to expect a regex to strip what I don't need from the string rather than matching what I do want, which is slightly annoying.. Also, the since it seems to match everything with `\\(.\\)`, I'm guessing it's using the global flag?

Please let me know if any of this isn't clear.

Comment: It would doubtless help to explain what you're wanting to do with the regexp.

Comment: Thanks for your questions @phils
I've edited the post to hopefully clarify it a bit.

Comment: WRT "this is via a package setting that asks for a regex string and I don't have much control over how it gets use" can you please add the details of what you're referring to here?  If we have the full context, there might be a nicer solution.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything to indicate that it's about Emacs - removed the tag.

Comment: Drew, it says "For context, this is supposed to run on emacs (in case it matters)." and as Emacs has its own regexp dialect (and moreover that I suspect the question might wind up not just being about regexp), I think it does matter, so I have restored the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs regular expressions can't trivially express "not foo" for arbitrary values of foo.  (The likes of PCRE have non-regular extensions for zero-width negative look-ahead/behind assertions, but in Emacs that sort of functionality is generally done with the support of lisp code<sup>1</sup>.)

You *can* still do it purely with regexp matching, but it's simply very cumbersome.  An Emacs regexp which matches any line which does *not* begin with `tags:` is:

`^\(?:$\|[^t]\|t[^a]\|ta[^g]\|tag[^s]\|tags[^:]\).*`

or if you need to enter it in the elisp double-quoted read syntax for strings:

`"^\\(?:$\\|[^t]\\|t[^a]\\|ta[^g]\\|tag[^s]\\|tags[^:]\\).*"`

---

<sup>1</sup> In lisp code you would instead simply check each line to see whether it *does* start with `tags:` and, if so, skip it (which is why Emacs generally gets away without the feature you're looking for, but of course that doesn't help you here).

Comment: You may also find `M-x re-builder` very helpful, along with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5568 to clarify some potential confusion regarding syntax.

Comment: Thanks for this @phils 

It seems your solution is close but it leaves the `tags:  ` which is not quite what I needed. This sort of pointed me in the right direction though, and I was able to put together something that works well!
`"^\\(?:\\(#\\+\\)?\\(?:filetags:\s+\\|tags:\s+\\|title:.*\\|identifier:.*\\|date:.*\\)\\|.*\\)"`
The only caveat here is that I've also added `(#\\+\\)?` so it also works for org meta options.

If you amend your solution, I'm more than happy to mark yours as it was very much the inspiration I needed :)

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  You've done something sufficiently different in the end that I don't think I should amend this answer, though -- go ahead and post+accept an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it for a bit and taken inspiration from @phils' answer, I've come up with the following:

```
"^\\(?:\\(#\\+\\)?\\(?:filetags:\s+\\|tags:\s+\\|title:.*\\|identifier:.*\\|date:.*\\)\\|.*\\)"
```

I've also added an extra `\\(#\\+\\)?` to account for org meta keys which would usually have the format `#+key: value`.